# How to find a (mathematical) function given some of its points (integers)

Tags: function, integer

I need to map a series of characters to integers, and I already know which characters map into which integers. I want to interpret that as a function from naturals to naturals (using the character's ASCII codes). What would be the best way to find that function?

Additional information: the function is constant throughout the program, the number of given points I have is small (less than 10), the integers I'm mapping to are sequential from 0 (that is, indexes of an array).

Obs. I am asking this question here because I think this has to be found by a program, but maybe I should be asking on the math site? Thank you.

Comment: Are you expecting it to be a particular *kind* of function? The best answer to this problem depends heavily on what kind of function you want to fit to your data. Also, is the function supposed to be defined on characters other than the few given ones?

Comment: No need to be defined on other characters. Also, I hope for a function that does not use floating point because, if the function is too complex, I'd better just do a series of conditional checks.

Comment: Something along the lines of indexing an array or writing a big `switch` is likely to be the best option. The way we would write such a function in pure math is essentially a giant else-if chain.